# JS DataTables 'All' Returns "No Matching Records Found"

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using JS DataTables and usually all of the functionality works just fine. I've noticed an interesting glitch, and I'm not sure what specifically causes it to happen.

My settings are at 15, 30, 50, All (`15, 30, 50, -1` respectively).

Basically, if I have a smaller row count, say < 100 everything seems to be fine. However, I'm noticing that when my row count gets into the thousands, the specific instance I'm seeing right now is 3847, then my 'All' option doesn't pull any data, it just says: "No Matching Records Found," even though there are 3847 records it should be displaying. Is this a limitation of JS DataTables? Does any one know how to get this to work properly and actually show everything, even if there is a lot of everything to show?

Code:

```
var useGetAllItems = result.Count > 400 ? false : true; // maybe this is part of the problem???
QueueTable = $('#tblQueue').dataTable({
    'aLengthMenu': [[15, 30, 50, -1], [15, 30, 50, "All"]],
    'aoColumnDefs': [
        { 'bSearchable': true, 'aTargets': ['_all'] },
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [3] },
        { 'bVisible': false, 'aTargets': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] },
        { 'iDataSort': 19, 'aTargets': [0] }
    ],
    'aoColumns': [
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 0);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 1); //invoice number and index
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 2); // company
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 3);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 4);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 5);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 6);
            }
        },
        {
            'sType': 'datetime-us', //used for sorting date time...
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 7);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 8);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 9);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 10);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 11);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 12);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 13);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 14);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 15);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 16);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 17);
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 18); // entered by
            }
        },
        {
            'mDataProp': function (obj, type, val) {
                return GetOrSetCellData(obj, type, val, 19); // prioritization sorting
            }
        }
    ],
    'aaSorting': [[5, 'asc']],
    'bAutoWidth': false,
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
    'oLanguage': {
        'sLengthMenu': 'Show _MENU_ Products per page',
        'sEmptyTable': 'No items in this queue.',
        'sInfoEmpty': 'Showing 0 to 0 of 0 Items',
        'sInfoFiltered': '(filtered from _MAX_ total Items)',
        'sInfo': 'Showing _START_ to _END_ of &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>_TOTAL_ Total Items in Queue</b>'
    },
    'bPaginate': true,
    'bStateSave': false,
    'iDisplayLength': 15,

    "bFilter": true,
    'bServerSide': !useGetAllItems,
    'bProcessing': false,

    'bDeferRender': true,

    'sAjaxSource': '/SalesModule/Orders/OrderProduct.asmx/GetOrderProductQueueEntries',
    'sAjaxDataProp': 'QueueEntries',

    'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
        aoData.push({ name: 'viewType', value: ViewType });
        aoData.push({ name: 'queueType', value: QueueType });

        // for server loading
        var pageIndex = Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength) + 1;
        var txSearch = $.trim($('#txSearch').val());

        aoData.push({ name: 'txSearch', value: txSearch });
        aoData.push({ name: 'pageIndex', value: pageIndex });
        aoData.push({ name: "useGetAllItems", value: useGetAllItems });

        // Filters if any
        var arrQueueFilters = [];
        for (var i = 9; i <= 18; i++)
            arrQueueFilters.push($("#ddlQueueFilter_" + i).val());
        aoData.push({ name: "arrQueueFilters", value: arrQueueFilters });

        if (useGetAllItems) {
            aoData.push({ name: "iDisplayStart", value: "0" });
            aoData.push({ name: "iDisplayLength", value: "15" });
            aoData.push({ name: "sEcho", value: "1" });
            aoData.push({ name: "sColumns", value: "0" });
            aoData.push({ name: "iColumns", value: "0" });
            aoData.push({ name: "iSortCol_0", value: "0" });
            aoData.push({ name: "sSortDir_0", value: "0" });
        }  
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': sSource,
            'data': GetSerializedJsonParams(aoData, ['viewType', 'queueType', 'txSearch', 'arrQueueFilters',
                    'useGetAllItems', 'pageIndex', 'iDisplayStart', 'iDisplayLength',
                    'sEcho', 'sColumns', 'iColumns', 'iSortCol_0', 'sSortDir_0']),

            'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': function (data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest) { 
                // Add 2 properties to each source data object .  These will be used later (in mDataProp function) to store dynamically rendered HTML
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.QueueEntries.length; i++) {
                    data.d.QueueEntries[i]._Display = {};
                    data.d.QueueEntries[i]._Sort = {};
                }
                hideUpdatingBox();
                fnCallback(data.d);
            },
            'error': function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve queue results from server.');
            }
        }); 
    },
    'sDom': 'fr<"dataTables_length_toolbar"T>ltip',
    'oTableTools': {
        'sSwfPath': '/js/jQuery.TableTools.Plugin/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf',
        'aButtons': [
        'print',
         {
             'sExtends': 'pdf',
             'mColumns': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             'sPdfOrientation': 'landscape'
         }
         ]
    },
    'fnRowCallback': function (nRow, rowObj, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        // Add/replace <tr> id w/ format: 'qrow_{opID}' 
        $(nRow).attr('id', 'qrow_{0}'.format(rowObj.Id));

        // All the queue classes that we support
        var allQueueColors = '{0}-{1}Red {0}-{1}Orange {0}-{1}Yellow'.format('queue', 'gradient');

        // Remove any existing <tr>, <td> queue color classes, <tr> queue-main class
        $(nRow).removeClass('{0} {1}'.format(allQueueColors, 'queue-parentrow 3'));
        $('td:eq(5)', nRow).removeClass(allQueueColors);

        // Add <tr> and <td> queue color classes
        $(nRow).addClass('{0} {1}'.format(rowObj.QueueColor, 'queue-parentrow'))
        $(nRow).addClass('{0} {1}'.format(rowObj.QueueColor, 'userId_'+ rowObj.EnteredByUsername))
        $('td:eq(5)', nRow).addClass(rowObj.QueueColor); 
        return nRow;
    },
    'fnInitComplete': function (oSettings, json) {
        $('#divTblLoading').hide();
        $('#tblQueue').fadeIn();
        $('#divQueueColorLegend').show();

        InitCountdownTimer();
        QueuePrioritization.OutputModal(); 

        // run filters on auto-refresh
        if (useGetAllItems) {
            InitQueueApplySelectedFilters();
        }
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        InitLightboxProofs(); // function in queue_page.js 
        hideUpdatingBox();
    }
});
```

Comment: are you using filtering ?

Comment: Yes, but none of the filters are enabled in this instance. The 15, 30, and 50 all work, it's only when I switch to -1 (all) that it decides there are no matching records.

Comment: can I have some code ?

Comment: Added the DataTable code.

Comment: 'bServerSide': !useGetAllItems, try removing  " ! " from here.

Comment: I've tried that, and then I hit the error: 'Failed to retrieve queue results from server.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that the problem wasn't with the JS DataTables at all. Basically there is a lot of back-end data processing on the server and when trying to do that on 1,000+ records, the AJAX request would time-out before the server could return a response. My solution was to not have an ALL drop-down, but a max of 1,000.